# How to fix bug where my enemies don't disappear?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want to make a Space Invaders game but my enemies don't disappear if they get hit. Does anyone know how to fix it?

I already tried a `for` loop (as you will see) but it doesnt work:

```
import turtle as tr
wn = tr.Screen()
wn.tracer(0)
bullet = tr.Turtle()
player = tr.Turtle()
enimis = []
y = -250
def shoot():
    player.direction = "up"
wn.onkey(shoot,"space")
while True:    
    if len(enimis) == 0:
        for u in range(-210,210,60):
            for o in range(100,260,60):
                enimi = tr.Turtle()
                enimi.setpos(u,o)
                enimis.append(enimi)
    if player.direction == "up":
        bullet.penup()
        x = player.xcor()
        bullet.setpos(x,y)
        bullet.pendown()
        for p in range(550):
            bullet.setpos(x,y+p)
            for k in enimis:
                if bullet.distance(k) < 25:
                    score += 10
                    if score > highscore:
                        highscored = True
                    else:
                        highscored = False
                    del k
                    hit = True
                    break
                else:
                    hit = False
    wn.update()
```

There aren't any error messages, the enemies just don't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're stuck on making dead enemies disappear when the code doesn't run at all due to this error:

```
    if player.direction == "up":
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'direction'
```

Nor could you hit an enemy since your player and enemies can't move and the player isn't pointing at an enemy to start with.  Too much *magical thinking* and not enough code.

To answer your question, this can't work:

```
for k in enimis:
    if bullet.distance(k) < 25:
        # ...
        del k
        # ...
        break
```

It either needs to be:

```
for k in enimis:
    if bullet.distance(k) < 25:
        # ...
        enimis.remove(k)  # remove by value
        # ...
        break
```

or:

```
for k in range(len(enimis)):
    if bullet.distance(enimis[k]) < 25:
        # ...
        del enimis[k]  # remove by index
        # ...
        break
```

Below is my complete rewrite of your code to get it to basically play: player can move left and right; bullets fire, hit enemies, score points, and enemies disappear; the score is shown on the screen; etc.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BASELINE = -250
FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'bold')

def left():
    player.setx(player.xcor() - 5)

def right():
    player.setx(player.xcor() + 5)

def shoot():
    global firing

    firing = True

firing = False
enemies = []
score = 0

bullet = Turtle('triangle')
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.speed('fastest')
bullet.shapesize(0.5)
bullet.setheading(90)
bullet.penup()

player = Turtle('turtle')
player.hideturtle()
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('green')
player.setheading(90)
player.penup()
player.sety(BASELINE)
player.showturtle()

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.penup()
marker.goto(-300, 300)
marker.write("Score: {}".format(score), align='center', font=FONT)

def play():
    global firing, score

    if not enemies:
        screen.tracer(False)

        for x in range(-210, 210, 60):
            for y in range(100, 260, 60):
                enemy = Turtle('turtle')
                enemy.color('red')
                enemy.setheading(270)
                enemy.penup()
                enemy.setpos(x, y)
                enemies.append(enemy)

        screen.tracer(True)

    if firing:

        bullet.setx(player.xcor())
        bullet.sety(BASELINE)
        bullet.showturtle()

        for p in range(0, 550, 5):

            bullet.sety(BASELINE + p)

            for enemy in enemies:
                if bullet.distance(enemy) < 20:
                    score += 10
                    marker.undo()
                    marker.write("Score: {}".format(score), align='center', font=FONT)
                    enemy.clear()
                    enemy.hideturtle()
                    enemies.remove(enemy)
                    break
            else:  # no break
                continue

            break

        bullet.clear()
        bullet.hideturtle()

        firing = False

    screen.ontimer(play, 100)

screen = Screen()

screen.onkey(shoot, 'space')
screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

play()

screen.mainloop()
```

Still needed: moving enemies left, right and down; making bullet firing and player/enemy movement happen at the same time; add back `highscore`; etc.

[image]